# ¿Cómo llenar un HTML solo teniendo el JSON sin AJAX ni PHP desde JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Lo que necesito realizar es que con el JSON que yo cree pueda hacer un HTML pero desconozco sinceramente como seria esto, se que seria con una función en JS pero no tengo la menor idea de como, es la primera vez que lo realizaria, les dejo el JSON que realize.

```
var informacion={
    "titulo":"Pratica 1",
    "cantidad_Preguntas":3,
    "preguntas":[{
        "pregunta_1":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
            "respuestas_pregunta1":[{
                "respuesta1_pregunta1":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta1_A":"Países",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta1_A":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
                }],
                "respuesta2_pregunta1":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta1_B":"Municipios",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta1_B":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta3_pregunta1":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta1_C":"Estados_/_provincias",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta1_C":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta4_pregunta1":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta1_D":"Continentes",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta1_D":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                    "correcta":true
                }],
                "respuesta5_pregunta1":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta1_E":"Islas",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta1_E":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
                }]
            }],
        "pregunta_2":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
            "respuestas_pregunta2":[{
                "respuesta1_pregunta2":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta2_A":"Países",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta2_A":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
                }],
                "respuesta2_pregunta2":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta2_B":"Municipios",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta2_B":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta3_pregunta2":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta2_C":"Estados_/_provincias",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta2_C":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta4_pregunta2":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta2_D":"Continentes",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta2_D":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                    "correcta":true
                }],
                "respuesta5_pregunta2":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta2_E":"Islas",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta2_E":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
                }],
        "pregunta_3":"¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
            "respuestas_pregunta3":[{
                "respuesta1_pregunta3":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta3_A":"Países",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta3_A":"Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
                }],
                "respuesta2_pregunta3":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta3_B":"Municipios",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta3_B":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta3_pregunta3":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta3_C":"Estados_/_provincias",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta3_C":"División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
                }],
                "respuesta4_pregunta3":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta3_D":"Continentes",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta3_D":"Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
                    "correcta":true
                }],
                "respuesta5_pregunta3":[{
                    "respuesta1_pregunta3_E":"Islas",
                    "ayuda1_pregunta3_E":"Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
console.log(informacion);
```

Comment: QUE orden les debes dar? Es decir una tabla?

Comment: Hola Jorge, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: La pregunta es incompleta. ¿Que necesitas conseguir?

Answer (score 0):

Jorge, no sé si será esto lo que estás buscando. 
He modificado un poco tu JSON pero la idea es la misma, no sé si será que al copiarlo se te ha ido un poco la estructura en la segunda pregunta.

Te he realizado un pequeño script en el que se realizan las siguientes funciones.

1. Creamos el formulario
2. Al pulsa el botón se valida que todo esté correctamente.

Espero que te sirva, un saludo.

```js
const asks = {
  "titulo": "Pratica 1",
  "cantidad_Preguntas": 3,
  "preguntas": [
    {
      "pregunta": "¿África, América, Antártida, Asia, Europa, y Oceanía son?",
      "respuestas": [
        {
          "respuesta": "Países",
          "ayuda": "Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Municipios",
          "ayuda": "División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Estados_/_provincias",
          "ayuda": "División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Continentes",
          "ayuda": "Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos.",
          "correcta": true
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Islas",
          "ayuda": "Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "pregunta": "¿Madrid, Cataluña, Andalucia son?",
      "respuestas": [
        {
          "respuesta": "Países",
          "ayuda": "Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado."
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Municipios",
          "ayuda": "División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Estados_/_provincias",
          "ayuda": "División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento.",
          "correcta": true
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Continentes",
          "ayuda": "Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos."
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Islas",
          "ayuda": "Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "pregunta": "¿España, Colombia, China y México son?",
      "respuestas": [
        {
          "respuesta": "Países",
          "ayuda": "Territorio, con características geográficas y culturales propias, que puede constituir una entidad política dentro de un Estado.",
          "correcta": true
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Municipios",
          "ayuda": "División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Estados_/_provincias",
          "ayuda": "División territorial administrativa en que se organiza un estado, que está regida por un ayuntamiento."
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Continentes",
          "ayuda": "Es cada una de las grandes extensiones en que se divide la superficie terrestre, separadas entre sí por los océanos."
        },
        {
          "respuesta": "Islas",
          "ayuda": "Es una zona de masa terrestre estable, más o menos extensa, rodeada completamente por una masa de agua."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
// Esta función nos permite crear un campos dentro del formulario 
function makeForm() {
  const form = document.getElementById('form-questions');
  if (form) {
    for (let i = 0; i < asks.preguntas.length; i++) {
      const ask = getFormElementFromQuestion(asks.preguntas[i], i);
      form.appendChild(ask);
    }
  }
}
/**
 * Devuelve una estructura html `
 *  <div ask>
       <p> Pregunta ... ... ..</p>
       <select>
        <option value="A">Paises</option>
        <option value="B">Municipios</option>
        <option value="C">Estados</option>
        <option value="D">Continentes</option>
        <option value="E">Islas</option>
       </select>
 *  </div>
 * `
 * 
 * @param {{pregunta: string, respuestas: [{respuesta:string, ayuda:string, correcta?:boolean}] } , index :number} question 
 * return  
 */
function getFormElementFromQuestion(question, index) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = question.pregunta;
  div.appendChild(p);
  for (let i = 0; i < question.respuestas.length - 1; i++) {
    const inputName = question.pregunta.replace(/ /g, '');
    const inputId = inputName + index;
    const label = document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute('for', inputId);
    label.innerHTML = question.respuestas[i].respuesta;
    div.appendChild(label);

    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'radio';
    input.id = inputId;
    input.name = inputName;
    input.value = question.respuestas[i].respuesta;
    div.appendChild(input);
    const br = document.createElement('br');
    div.appendChild(br);

  }
  return div;
}


function checkAsk() {
  const form = document.getElementById('form-questions');
  const respuestas = [];
  if (form) {
    const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
    for (i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
      // obtenemos el objeto pregunta que corresponde con el input
      const ask = asks.preguntas.find((pregunta) => {
        return pregunta.pregunta.replace(/ /g, '') === inputs[i].name;
      });

      const correctAnswer = ask.respuestas.find((respuesta) => {
        return respuesta.correcta;
      });
      let isCorrect = false;
      if (correctAnswer.respuesta === inputs[i].value) {
        isCorrect = true;
      }

      const respuesta = { pregunta: ask.pregunta, esCorrecta: isCorrect };

      respuestas.push(respuesta);
    }
  }
  console.log(respuestas);
  const corrects = respuestas.filter((respuesta) => {
    return respuesta.esCorrecta
  });

  if (corrects.length === respuestas.length) {
    alert('Has acertado todas');
  } else {
    alert('Has tenido algún fallo');
  }

  return respuestas;
}


function main() {
  makeForm();
}


main();
```

```html
   <div id="form-container">
      <form id="form-questions">

      </form>
      <button onclick="checkAsk()"> Comprobar preguntas</button>
    </div>
```